# Orchard: Facebook authentication

Tags: oauth, orchardcms, dotnetopenauth, facebook-authentication, orchardcms-1.6

I need to add Facebook authentication to Orchards local user system, using OpenAuth (not necessarily, but preferred).

Is there any module for that (that I am not aware of) or should I implement it myself? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can make a search on the gallery, and you can clone this: http://orchardopenauth.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate your help.